# python discord.ui: get modal from view

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to make view that shows modal dialog.

Here code, with sample view that opens modal via button

```
import discord
from discord import ApplicationContext
from constant import BOT_TOKEN

bot = discord.Bot()


class TimeRoleModal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, title: str) -> None:
        item = discord.ui.InputText(label="Sample input text:")
        super().__init__(item, title=title)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return


class TimeRoleView(discord.ui.View):
    _ctx: ApplicationContext = None

    def __init__(self, ctx: ApplicationContext):
        super().__init__()
        self._ctx = ctx

    @discord.ui.button(row=2, label="30", style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary)
    async def button2_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        modal = TimeRoleModal("SampleTitle")
        await self._ctx.send_modal(modal)
        await interaction.response.defer()


@bot.user_command()
async def timerole(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext, member: discord.Member):
    view = TimeRoleView(ctx=ctx)
    await ctx.send("Test view with button + modal", view=view, delete_after=15)

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

method send_modal throws exception
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

Whats wrong, is it generally possible?

Comment: what do you have in `TimeRoleModal` ?

Comment: maybe create `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and test it.

Comment: edited - fully (not) worked code placed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an error in button handler - should use interaction direcly passed into button handler, not sending modal from context

```
@discord.ui.button(row=2, label="30", style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary)
async def button2_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    modal = TimeRoleModal("SampleTitle")
    await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
    await modal.wait()
```

This works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).